# C++ why accessing dynamic array is used without the asterisk operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int *a;
a = new int[2];
a[1] = 1;

}
```

From what I understand, a 2 sized array of int is allocated in "the heap memory" and pointer `a` takes the memory address of that newly created array. However, when trying to access (for example) the second index of the array (`a[1]`), it simply does so without the asterisk operator and I don't understand why, I'm used to seeing that the value stored in a memory address pointed to by a pointer is accessed as `*pointername` and not like `pointername[value]`.
So my question is, why do we use the subscript operator to access a pointer which points to an array without the asterisk operator?

Comment: It means the same thing in practice however in C++ a class can overload the [] operator, so it's better to use that (obviously int * doesn't).

Comment: Accessing a[1] is not accessing the first, but the SECOND element, c arrays indexes are zero-based.

Comment: Avoid coding like this. Use C++11 [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), e.g. `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: The pointer `a` points *to the first element* of the array - it is a pointer to an `int`. A pointer to an array of `int` looks like this: `int (*ap)[2];`. If you had a pointer to an array you would indeed have to write `(*ap)[1] = 1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, applying `operator[]` to a pointer `p` with index `i` is the semantic equivalent of

```
*(p + i)
```

and

```
*(i + p)
```

You can think of it as syntactic sugar. Also note that this implies that `p[N]` is equivalent to `N[p]`.

Answer (score 1):

`a[N]` is equal to `*(a+N)` if `a` is a pointer. Thus, `a[1]` dereferences the pointer `a+1`.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a block of memory containing multiple instances of same size elements,
the subscript operator just puts an offset for the right element from the original pointer. so a[0] would be equal to *a. and a[1] = *a + 1 * sizeof(element) so in a sense you are right we do use the asterisk operator in the end it's just hidden behind syntactic sugar.

Comment: `a[1]` is `*(a+1)`, not `*a + 1*sizeof(element)`.

Comment: Yes but then you need to know that incrementing a pointer will increment it by the size of what's pointed to. so in essence they are the same thing, the sizeof makes the explanation a bit more clear (imo)

Comment: You do not need to know that. That knowledge is built in to the language. `a+1` points to the second element of `a`, not the second byte.

Answer (score 0):

Ihe index operator has a peculiar meaning for an array of primitives: `array[index]` is equivalent to `*(array+index)`. One side effect is that if you want to obfuscate your code, `index[array]` means exactly the same thing (for primitive types, of course). For primitive arrays, the index operator is semantic sugar for a dereference.

For non-primitive types, classes can override `operator[]`. This is the opposite of semantic sugar.